# Close and reset Tornado IOLoop after KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, tornado

I occasionally want to expose logic within tornado coroutines to interactive users.  These users often press `Ctrl-C` to interrupt long-running computations.  This puts the IOLoop in an unhappy state for future interactions.

```
In [1]: from tornado import gen
In [2]: from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
In [3]: IOLoop.current().run_sync(lambda: gen.sleep(100000))
KeyboardInterrupt: 

In [4]: IOLoop.current().run_sync(lambda: gen.sleep(1))
RuntimeError: IOLoop is already running
```

What operations should I do in between `[3]` and `[4]` to clean up or replace the stuck IOLoop.  Some combination of `.stop`, `.close`, `.close_current` and `.close_instance` have worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a `KeyboardInterrupt`, the `IOLoop` is left in an undefined state and cannot be safely restarted. (This is true of most objects: it is rare for an object to still be usable after a method has been interrupted unless that method was read-only).

If you want to be able to recover from `C-c` you'll have to write your own signal handler instead of using the default one which raises `KeyboardInterrupt`. For example, to simply stop the `IOLoop` and leave it in a restartable state, you could do something like this (untested):

```
def sigint_handler(sig, frame):
    io_loop = IOLoop.current()
    io_loop.add_callback_from_signal(io_loop.stop())
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sigint_handler)
```

If you want to raise an exception after being interrupted in this way, you'll have to make changes to the code that calls `IOLoop.start`.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not looking to reactivate the current IOLoop.  I would be quite satisfied discarding it and making a new one.

Comment: Ah, that's much simpler. You can try to call `close()` on the old one but be prepared for an exception. Calling `install()` (if the previous IOLoop was the `instance()`) and `make_current()` should be enough to replace the old one. But this is still subject to change in future versions of Tornado; the only way that's really guaranteed to be safe is to replace the signal handler with one that doesn't raise `KeyboardInterrupt`.